# Geotagging vs. Keywording

Tags: lightroom-4, geotagging, keywords

I used to keyword all my photos with the "Where?" keywords so that I easily could find photos from a certain location. But with the arrival of Lightroom 4 geotagging and reverse geocoding has become a great and efficient option.

My question is if there is any reason why I should continue using location keywords (in usual keywords field) anymore or if geocoding is enough.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your own purposes, the geolocation features might serve well to help you "locate" your photos.  Consider export, however... if you're sharing those photos elsewhere and that venue doesn't have a geolocation search, folks might be searching for keywords.

Let's say you have a bunch of great images of your city and you put them online... if folks search for your city by keyword, will they find them?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.
So it's best to assume that most  on line photo sharing services won't let users search by the IPTC location fields but only the "standard" keywords field?